# After removing an address from office autocomplete it does not pup up again

Tags: outlook, office365, ms-office

I have the following issue that after removing a autocomplete suggestion once like here:
[image]

I cant get this address back in the autocomplete. I did it by accident and want to get it back. Any suggestion how?